# VBA google search

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning to use excel VBA to automate a google search with my codes shown below. However, i always encounter 'run time error 424:  object required' at the line indicated below. I have already declared searchtxt as my object yet error still occured. I tried to remove the searchtxt object declaration but it still does not work. Can someone help me to correct my code error so that i can do a google search in vba. Thank You

```
Sub google_search()
Dim searchtxt As Object, myie As Object

Set myie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
With myie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https:\\www.google.com"
    Do While .Busy
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do While .readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End With

Set searchtxt = myie.document.getelementbyid("q")  'error occured here
Set searchtxt.Value = "excel vba"
myie.document.forms(0).submit

End Sub
```

Comment: I did a search on the source code for the webpage in question and did not find any elements with "q" as an ID, so that will return `NULL` - which is a value that you cannot set to an `Object` variable. So that would explain why you are getting the error. You are looking for something that does not exist.

Comment: `Set searchtxt.Value = "excel vba"` you  cannot use `Set` here - Value is not an object-type property, and "excel vba" is a String.

Comment: @braX that means the solution is to find the right input name? How do i know which is the right name? Below is my inspect element in my google search. Pls take a look.<input name="q" title="Search" class="gLFyf gsfi" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false" autofocus="" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-label="Search" type="text" maxlength="2048" value="" jsaction="paste:puy29d" data-ved="0ahUKEwiAzN3vwenoAhUZXn0KHWruC24Q39UDCAQ" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" value=""></input>

Comment: an input's NAME is not the same thing as an ID assigned to it. And note what Tim said too... Wherever you are learning how to do this from is not a good resource. (Please dont say you are using YoutTube to learn how to code)

Comment: You are over complicating things. `https://www.google.com.au/search?q=lynx+armor+vehicle`

Comment: @Tim Williams thanks for the correction

Comment: @braX Thank you for your advice. Indeed i learn this from youtube. What is the correct input ID i should write in my code for this google search?

Comment: `getElementsByName("q")(0)`  The `(0)` is because that method returns a collection, even when there's only one match.

Comment: @TIm Williams i followed this way. But another error occurred "type mismatched"

Comment: On the same line?

Comment: @Tim Williams thanks for your code. I tried again today and there is no error and it works well

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to fill the search form on the Google page and press submit. You can just navigate using your search term:

```
.Navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=your search term"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub InternetExplorer()

Dim ie As Object
Dim searchtxt As Object
Dim searchres As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
   With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.google.co.in"

    Do While .busy
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Do While .readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set searchtxt = .document.querySelector("input[name='q']")

    searchtxt.Value = "Shaktman"

   .document.forms(0).submit
    End with

    End sub
```

The 'getElementById' method is used to select an element by its unique ID attribute, which should be unique across the entire HTML document. However, the Google search box does not have an ID of "q", but instead has a name attribute of "q", which is not unique and can be used by multiple elements on the same page.

To select an element with a specific name attribute, you can use the querySelector method with an attribute selector. In this case, you can use the attribute selector [name='q'] to select the input element with a name attribute of "q". Hence above Code would be correct to perform with InternetExplorer